How can I encourage my toddler to try new foods?
I have a two year old daughter who is generally a very good eater. When she was a bit younger she was always willing to at least take a bite of two of any new food that I would put on her plate, but lately she has started to completely refuse anything outside of her set of favorite foods. Those favorite foods are pretty varied, so it could be worse, but I really want to encourage her to try more things (especially vegetables, where she unsurprisingly the most picky).
I've tried including a food that I know she likes (typically fruit or pasta or meatballs/loaf) on the plate with the new food, but she'll just eat the thing she likes and then throw her plate on the floor with the stuff she doesn't want to try. I understand that part of this is the developmentally normal boundary testing that they do at this age, but I've come up short trying to get her to try new foods that I really think she would enjoy based on the things that she does eat. I'm not super thrilled about the "you eat this or you eat nothing" method that I've had recommended to me, especially since she always seems to choose the latter when we resort to it.

Do you (or your wife) eat the foods she doesn't like, in front of her? Or is she the only one supposed to eat them?

Usually my wife isn't home from work yet when we do dinner time, but I always try to sit down with her and eat the same thing she's eating.

I've had luck appealing to the senses, like with cucumber, I'll take a bite and try to emphasize how loud and crunchy it is. Make it fun that they can make the crunch noise themselves.

As a small child, I just loved mashed potatoes: my mother made a volcano on my plate, but some gravy in the crater and when I started eating the mash, I could see the lava coming out of the volcano :-)

This is something I've researched fairly extensively. I think what you're looking to do is something like this:

For foods that your child doesn't like, just keep presenting them even if they don't eat them. In an ideal scenario your kid will warm up to the food eventually with enough presentations. If they're absolutely adamant that they don't like the food on repeated presentations, then stop presenting it for a while.
It's generally ok if they don't eat the food that you present them, but if they want something else what you're wanting to avoid is giving them unhealthy alternatives. My wife and I would generally let them have alternatives, but they had to be healthy
The main thing you want to avoid is making meal time combative, work with your kid, not against them. Don't worry about what they do or don't eat, just make sure they're getting healthy options.

To go back to the main question, you can't really force your kid to eat something they don't like, but studies show that they're more likely to change their mind with repeated presentations, sometimes upwards of ten presentations. This isn't a guarantee but it's generally the only approach you can take. If your kid won't eat what you present, don't make a big deal about it.

"sometimes upwards of ten presentations" is a very helpful data point actually. I was definitely getting discouraged much sooner than that, so it's good to know that it might just take a bit more patience (who would have guessed :P)

You'll have wins and losses. One of my kids absolutely won't eat squash, the other one won't eat tomatoes no matter what I do. Sometimes they just don't like a food. Other foods can catch.

Luckily tomatoes are one of the most reliable foods, we attribute it to the Italian side of my wife's family :)

While "you eat this or you eat nothing" is certainly to dramatic you can and should produce a setting where the new food has a fair chance to be tried. If you present food she likes in parallel with new unknown food then her choice is essentially between eating something she knows she will like versus something unknown that may or may not be tasty. Of course she will just pick the food she likes, it is the better choice.
A better setup would be something like today we are all eating the new food. Full stop. The parents also eating it helps. If she really doesn't like it she can have some bread afterwards. She is not going to go hungry and should be aware of that safety. But from the options she has available trying the new food looks like the best choice. If she honestly tried and didn't like it that should be okay and then you can offer alternatives.

This is anecdotal, but I'm the father of four fussy eating girls, one of whom has gone on to develop a significant eating disorder.  Numbers one and two were raised in a rules-based approach, numbers three and four were raised in a child-led way.  The eating disorder is among the first two.  The later two are now approaching high school age, and have a much healthier attitude to food.
My advice would be to offer choice about what is eaten and when.  Insist on nothing.  Don't label ANY food as "bad".  Young children are absorbing the minutiae of social expectations around food before they can even speak.

One common approach is to establish a rule that the child should try the food offered to them, and then say if they like it or not. If they don't, then there is no point to insist, but often they refuse to try simply because it is new or because it looks unappealing (from their point of view.)
One can also compare/liken the food to something they know or like - e.g., calling string beans "green french fries". Creating visually appealing foods, like spinach pancakes can occasionally do the trick as well.
Another important point is that a child used to a variety of foods is more open to new tastes. In this sense, one should not expect immediate results, but keep in mind that cultivating their taste goes a long way in healthy eating in future.
Update
In view of the comments, I would like to add a few clarifications:

There is nothing wrong with suggesting to a child to try new foods (which is what the whole discussion is about.) Making it a rule that they should try new food before refusing it seems quite appropriate for toddlers, who would accept it just as another rule alongside washing hands, going to toilet, saying "hello/goodbye", etc.
Some insinuated that my second paragraph invites lying to children.
What I was suggesting is more to amuse them and thus change their attitude: "Look, the string beans are just like green fries! - Wow! Green fries! Yummy!"
Furthermore, many foods exists in both a dessert/sweet variety and in a non-sweet variety, served as the main dish. E.g., spinach waffles make miracles when it comes to poor eaters. Likewise, buckweat pancakes, although originally from Brittany, are nowadays as much a staple of fast French food, as kebab or McDonals/Burgerking/etc.
A caveat: one should not expect a child to adopt more varied food habits than those of parents. So if some of the menu suggestions above come as something exotic to you, rather than just another thing to try alongside your usual cooking, then they will be of little help. (IMHO, in general, child learns much more from how parents really are, than from what they teach/preach.)


Do you have any source or data for your second paragraph? My instinct is that likening food to something it's not actually like would be a good way to lose your kid's trust when it comes to food. I would also imagine that prompting the brain to expect a certain taste and then providing a different taste would be less likely to provoke a positive response than providing no prompt at all.

I'd also be interested in a source for the first paragraph.  While such a rule is fine (though moot) for kids happy to try new foods, I wonder if it's problematic for those who are not.

@Brian this is a standard approach in French public childcare. Obviously, one should not force a child, but many new habits are formed in this age (washing hands, using a spoon, going to toilets), and food-related habits are a part of these.

@AAM111 Please take no offense, but you cannot expect someone to disprove seriously claims based on intuition/beliefs - see Burden of proof. IMHO, children do not lose trust in their carers when they learn that tomato is not a vegetable or that hamburger has no ham in it (Santa Claus or religion are more serious issues, since they are socially and culturally enforced, and affect worldview.) [contd.]

@AAM111 [contd.] Perhaps a clarification is needed regarding the pancakes - in France many foods come in sweet/salted varieties, so I am talking about introducing a food that is similar to the food that the child likes. Also, french fries can be made of vegetables other than potato (e.g., sweet potatoes, or even raw carrots - as in (French?) BurgerKing.) In any case, I am not inviting anyone to lie to a child.

@RogerV. AAM's comment does not disprove the claim, but you haven't proved it yet. And your example with comparing string beans to french fries certainly feels like a lie, because while similar in shape, they are very different in taste and texture

@Yksisarvinen I didn't make any claims - only suggestions. However AAM does claim that such innocent actions can cause a loss of trust and or confusion, without providing any proof. I also do not see how calling string beans green fries is a lie - the child clearly sees that they are different and taste differently, but it makes it more of an amusing activity ("Wow, green fries!")

@Yksisarvinen to tell the truth, I find your and AAM's posts really scary - they seem to be grounded in the attitude towards children, completely devoid of any feeling, sense of complicity,  or other emotions. Now emotional deprivation is indeed a well-known problem.

AAM asked for a source of your suggestion, it was you who brought proves into discussion, so I explained that in this case burden of proof lies on you. If you have no source, you could've said "I have none" or "that's a suggestion based on my experience". Example with fries is not like learning that tomato is not a vegetable, it's more akin to parents telling children that drawing blood will not hurt and then child can feel a sharp sensation (which may not be painful to us, but is painful to the kid).

The way this example could work is if parent held the bean and said "hey, look, that looks just like a green fry!" and proceed to play with it a bit or say "I wonder if tastes the same? Hmm, not really, but it's also good". Instead, I read your post as going for just "these are just like green fries" and that would be a lie. Also, diagnosing emotional deprivation from two sentences is just wild.

@Yksisarvinen you seem to drawn quite a lot  from two sentences in my post - I am just demonstrating that two can play this game. As you also correctly pointed out, the problem is not with my post, but your reading of it... and yet, instead of politely asking for a clarification,  you are trying to muscle me. As you see, I have already quite a bit for a psychological profile.

"and then say if they like it or not" - I am not sure about this - my daughter has often told me she "doesn't like" something when she means it's not her favourite delicious food.... And the second paragraph didn't work on me and it doesn't work on my son or daughter - kids aren't stupid! Wouldn't be long before I'd be making pancakes and getting raised eyebrows ("Are they spinach pancakes or real pancakes?")

@komodosp my experience is that once they try it, they often like it and eat it - even if they might keep repeating that "it is disgusting". I clarified in the comments above that(at least in France) many foods exist in sweet and non-sweet variety (the latter as the main dish) - a child clearly knows which one is which. Yet, I have seen many bad eaters "converted" to spinach waffles. Buckweat pancakes originally come from Brittany, but are widely consumed in France alongside kebab and McDonalds.
